# Pybind - Invoke Function with Shared-Pointer to Derived Class

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++17, pybind11

I have the following setup (1 Base class, 1 Derived class, 1 Container). The container takes a `shared_ptr<Base>` as an input.

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

struct Base { };
struct Derived : public Base { };

struct Container { void input(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& ptr) { } };

PYBIND11_MODULE(PybindTest, m)
{
    py::class_<Base,    std::shared_ptr<Base>>(m, "Base").def(py::init<>());
    py::class_<Derived, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>(m, "Derived").def(py::init<>());

    py::class_<Container, std::shared_ptr<Container>>(m, "Container")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("input", &Container::input);
}
```

In C++ I can pass either `shared_ptr<Base>` or `shared_ptr<Derived>` to the `input` function. But in Python I get an error:

```py
import PybindTest as p
p.Container().input(p.Base())      # All good
p.Container().input(p.Derived())   # Throws Error

# TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-10-70fe5b9f3a41> in <module>
#       1 import PybindTest as p
#       2 p.Container().input(p.Base())
# ----> 3 p.Container().input(p.Derived())
# 
# TypeError: input(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
#     1. (self: PybindTest.Container, arg0: PybindTest.Base) -> None
# 
# Invoked with: <PybindTest.Container object at 0x0000022378B4FF80>, <PybindTest.Derived object at 0x0000022378B4FCE0>
```

I've tried playing around with things like

```cpp
.def("input", py::overload_cast<const std::shared_ptr<Derived>&> (&Container::input))
.def("input", [](const std::shared_ptr<Derived> & ptr) { this->input(ptr); })
```

but neither of those two compile. **Any advice?**

*I use Windows 10 with Python 3.6 x64 and compile everything with VS 2019.*

Comment: You may want to inform Python that Base is a base for Derived, via an extra argument for `class_`.

Comment: Where exactly in order sequence of `class_` would I add that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @n.m. suggested:

```cpp
py::class_<Derived, std::shared_ptr<Derived>, Base>(m, "Derived")
    .def(py::init<>());
```

From [pybind11 documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#inheritance-and-automatic-upcasting) (Method 1: template parameter)